# How could I retrieve Shared Preferences in another activity?

Tags: android

I would like to retrieve the values ​​saved in the shared preferences in one activity to use these values ​​in another activity. I know that the values ​​saved in the shared preferences are usable in all the activities of the app. Anyone know how I could do? Thanks in advance to everyone!
This is the code for saving shared preferences in my MenuActivity:

```
private final String DefaultEmailValue = "";
private String email;
private final String DefaultUsernameValue = "";
private String userName;
private static final String PREFS_NAME = "preferences";
private static final String PREF_EMAIL = "Email";
private static final String PREF_USERNAME = "Username";


    private void savePreferences() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

        // Edit and commit
        email = mEmail.getText().toString();
        userName = mUsername.getText().toString();
        System.out.println("onPause save email: " + email);
        System.out.println("onPause save username: " + userName);
        editor.putString(PREF_EMAIL, email);
        editor.putString(PREF_USERNAME, userName);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private void loadPreferences() {

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // Get value
        email = settings.getString(PREF_EMAIL, DefaultEmailValue);
        userName = settings.getString(PREF_USERNAME, DefaultUsernameValue);
        mEmail.setText(email);
        mUsername.setText(userName);
        System.out.println("onResume load email: " + email);
        System.out.println("onResume load username: " + userName);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You already know method.
You got field from Preferences in one activity.

You can get field value in another activity with same method as before.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String email = prefs .getString("Email", "");
```

Comment: So I should make public: static final String PREF_EMAIL = "Email"; so it could be visible in another activity and use it like first argument in getString?

Comment: yes, if you don't want make it public, you need to copy define and paste it to another activity.

Comment: thank you very much mate, and for the second argument in getString() what could I use?

Comment: it's default value, if you didn't save email address before, getString() returns default value. So you could use null or empty string or default email address.

Comment: So having saved the email of the logged in user, getString () should return that email to me? As I need it to update the database on firebase

Comment: yes, SharedPreference saved data to file in internal storage. So you can save your email in SharedPreference.

Comment: Thank you very much, you were very kind and you answered exhaustively. I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You save your values to SharedPreferences by name. Just retrieve needed value by name on other Activity. SharedPreferences is a storage for your app, not only for Activity. You can retrieve data from any place where you can instantiate SharedPreference instance.